# Unable to access port inside Docker

Tags: windows, docker, crate, kitematic

What could be wrong if the docker port cannot be accessed via the Access URL:

[image]

https://hub.docker.com/r/library/crate/

Comment: Maybe I dont understand your question. but from docker container you should be able to access your service via `127.0.0.1:4200` and outside of container your service should be accessible from `192.168.99.100:33385`. If you want to access through the same port you should map this port with eg. `-p 4200:4200`

Comment: "Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'"

Comment: what kind of client you are using? or how are you trying to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `crate` is listening on `127.0.0.1` it won't be accessible from outside the world since for the host `127.0.0.1` means something else. So you need to make your crate container listen on host IP. You can do that using:

```
$ docker run --net=host -d crate crate -Cnetwork.host=_site_
```

Details [here](https://crate.io/docs/crate/guide/getting_started/install/containers/docker.html). Also, there is change in release `2.X.X` which is causing trouble for a lot of people it says:

> Changed default bind and publish address from 0.0.0.0 to the system
>   loopback addresses which will result in CrateDB listening only to
>   local ports.

Have a look at release notes [here.](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/release_notes/2.0.0.html)